# Complex dataType in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-query

Hi Is there any option to create hive table on below hdfs file.So lets say if I query with on customer then it should return all the columns for customer in a single row in json format.

Hdfs File Content:

```
{
"customer": {
    "legalBusinessName": "testing",
    "organisationIdentifications": [{
        "type": "test",
        "identification": "test102.abc@xyz"
    }, {
        "type": "test",
        "identification": "12345678"
    }]
},
"seller": {
    "legalBusinessName": "testing",
    "organisationIdentifications": [{
        "type": "test",
        "identification": "test"
    }]
},

"RecommendationId": "testid",
"excludedRemittanceInformation": [],
"recommendedPaymentInstructions": [{
    "executionDate": "2022-06-12",
    "remittanceInformation": {
        "structured": [{
            "referredDocumentInformation": [{
                "paymentDueDate": "2022-06-12",

                "referredDocumentAmount": {
                    "duePayableAmount": 3000
                }
            }]
        }]
    }
}]
```

}

File Structure :

[image]

Comment: can you try this link  https://www.hivetablegenerator.com/ ? this generated hive table DDL from your json.

Comment: @KoushikRoy Yes Tried. But not able to select the data.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71701670/row-is-not-a-valid-json-object-jsonexception-hive

Kindly Suggest.